# Adding input in jQuery and problem adding several input with a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

Why after a click on add, adding several input together?
I want once times add input in each click on add.
you see yourself : [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/539LR/3/)

Comment: Are you looking to add a new input, a new .mediumCell or a .column?

Comment: Yes, everything in between classes '.adding', '.ai_service'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this js fiddle I think I have done wat you wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/539LR/6/

Here is the js code

```
$('a.add_input').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $column = $(this).closest("div.column");
    var input = $column.prev("div.column").clone().wrap("<div />").parent().html();
    $column.before($(input));

});
```

Comment: after click on add several input together adding . Here you can put the code?

Comment: I am sorry the link which I pasted was wrong. Please check my edited answer it has the right link as well as the code too.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want.  It grabs a column, duplicates it, sets the input to "" and inserts it before the "add" button

http://jsfiddle.net/n4YFK/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `var input = $(".ai_service").find(":eq(0)").html();` instead. See http://jsfiddle.net/539LR/4/ for reference

Comment: no, i not want adding 1 input(it is Unlimited ), i want with each times click add 1 input in class input that clicked.

Comment: then you should remove $(this).remove() from the script, because it removes the add link http://jsfiddle.net/539LR/5/

Comment: my problem not remove add input, my problem is: after a click on add, adding several input together